# Spring MVC validation error styling

Tags: spring-mvc, styles, validation

I would like to style my forms in case of errors a bit more.
Standard-usage is to print the error with help of `<f:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />`

But I want to mark the corresponding text fields as well - maybe by adding an additional style.

Can this be done in an easy way?

Thanks in advance and cheers

Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So late, but it can be useful for someone else.
A very easy way now, using the **cssErrorClass**, i.e.:
`<form:input path="id" class="form-control height30px" cssErrorClass="form-control height30px error"/>`

Answer (score 3):

One easy way I can think of is:

```
<c:set var="inputCls" value="niceInputCls" scope="page" />

<form:errors path="name" cssClass="error">
<c:set var="inputCls" value="errorInputCls" scope="page" />
</form:errors>
```

And in your input tag:

```
<form:input path="name" cssClass="${inputCls}" />
```

You can define your normal input and error input style classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I have a page with lets say 20 form fields, I have to add his to every form field? Is there a more generic and simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as well for the input fields here is that example :

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-errors-tag-example/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is actually not the solution I wanted. I want to add a custom style to the <input> field itself; for example to give it a red border.